# What stat analises to use? In SPSS

Tags: spss, manova

What analises to use? MANOVA? And how?
 I have a following design:
Two groups made the same task and the result I have in Reaction times ( dependent variable). I have three additional variables (independent) that might have influenced that result.

What statistic command to use? I tried GLM but I can’t Choose my dependent variable when entering syntax.

Appropriate your time

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say, given what you described.

If I understand correctly, you have one dependent variable (reaction time) and four independent variables. That sounds like a "univariate GLM" (look up UNIANOVA in the Help). Categorical independent variables (like "group", in your case binary) would be the "factors" and the continuous independent variables the "covariates."

Something like this:

`UNIANOVA <dependent variable> BY <factor(s)> WITH <covariate(s) / <other options>.`